# Fullcalender on click event title alert id of the clicked title

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

How can I access event id in alert when click on specific event title?

Please take a look at this Image:

[image]

As in Image, when some click on "**Custome Event - Loading**" , its id should show in alert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not very sure if this is what you want but you can do this, which on click on an event alert the id.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        alert(calEvent.id)

    }
});
```